# Testing React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

I've been scratching my head trying to find a way to test what props are passed into my React components I have written. See example:

FirstName.js

```
export default FirstName = (props) => {
 return (
   <Select value={props.value} />
 );
}
```

Select.js

```
export default Select = (props) => {
 return (
   <div>props.value</div>
 );
}
```

The test I want to write is for the FirstName component, I want to make sure that the value prop is passed into the Select Components value property.

However currently the only way I can validate this is to assert on the output of Select.js which is not a part of the unit I am testing, so I really would rather not make the FirstName.test.js file be dependent on changes that happen inside of Select.js.

One solution I've heard is to use `jest.mock('path/to/Select.js')` OR

```
jest.mock('../moduleName', () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: jest.fn(),
  };
});
```

however for some reason the Select inside my test IS the mock function, but the Select inside of the FirstName.js is not, so for some reason it stubs it for the test but not for the running code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try it in next way

```
import FirstName from '../src/FirstName';
describe('<FirstName />', () => {
  const mockProps = { name: 'name', };
  it('Check Select props', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<FirstName {...mockProps} />);
    expect(wrapper.find('Select').props()).toBe(mockProps);
  });

});
```

Comment: Project doesn't  currently have enzyme installed but perhapse if I want to do this form of testing I will need to add it.

Cheers
Michael.